# What to store in SQL Table? File's path or some other

Tags: php, sql-server, image, file-upload

I created a php signin page which stores the First Name, Last Name, User name and Password from users, and it is working okay. I added one more option to upload user's image. The image is uploading successfully in my images directory. Now the question is that, when i login the page with the information which i have stored in sql express table, all the info i am able to get. like username, first name and last name. Now i want to get the image which i uploaded at the time of sign in. please let me help, how to store the image or its path into sql express table and how to retrieve it when a particular user login.

Comment: Be careful storing passwords. They should never be stored in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first when you submit the form while registering, you should have to upload the file on the server and save its path to the db and when you are showing the information. you can get it from the db and echo it in

```
<img src="<?php echo $path_from_db; ?>">
```

That's how it works.

Comment: thnks for your ans, but how to find uploaded path of any file. if i use "$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])" it shows the temporary path. i want the exact path where my file has been moved.

Comment: when you submit teh form you file stored in temp folder. so you have to move into permanent directory on your server. So you have to move file into that directory you want to store that file like this `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]))` the your path to store in db is `$target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])` see at [how to upload file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)